# How to apply a click impulse to a "movable" object from Windows.Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some picture boxes (billiard balls) in a Windows Forms and I want to make them collide. In the initial condition they are at rest and I want to apply an impulse to one of them. The way I was thinking this problems was like this:

I have two events:

- Form1_MouseDown => (here I click on a ball and I want to check that click is on it, I start a timer, and I want to get the initial mouse coordinates)
- Form1_MouseUp   => (here I want to stop the timer, in order to measure time interval, also I want to get the final mouse coordinates).

Having in mind, the time interval, the initial and the final point of the mouse position (the distance between these two), I can mathematically express the click impulse on a ball.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Ball b1;
    public Ball b2;
    public Ball b3;
    public Ball b4;
    public Ball b5;
    public Ball b6;
    public Ball[] list;

    double time;
    ushort first_ball;
    bool started = false;
    Point Start;
    Point End;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        b1 = new Ball(ref p1, 0, 0);
        b2 = new Ball(ref p2, 0, 0);
        b3 = new Ball(ref p3, 0, 0);
        b4 = new Ball(ref p4, 0, 0);
        b5 = new Ball(ref p5, 0, 0);
        b6 = new Ball(ref p6, 0, 0);
        list = new Ball[] { b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6 };
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var z in list)
            Ball.Move(z, this);
        for(ushort i=0; i < list.Length; i++)
           for(ushort j=i; j< list.Length; j++)
            {
                if (i != j) 
                {
                    if (Ball.distance(list[i].Center, list[j].Center) < (list[i].ball.Width / 2 + list[j].ball.Width / 2))
                    {
                        list[i].vx *= -1;
                        list[i].vy *= -1;
                        list[j].vx *= -1;
                        list[j].vy *= -1;
                    }

                }
            }

    }

    // here starts the problematic part

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        Start.X = MousePosition.X;
        Start.Y = MousePosition.Y;
        for (ushort i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            if(Start.X < list[i].ball.Left + list[i].ball.Width && Start.X > list[i].ball.Left && Start.Y < list[i].ball.Top + list[i].ball.Height && Start.Y > list[i].ball.Top)
            {
                timer2.Start();
                started = true;
                first_ball = i;
            }
                    
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        timer2.Stop();
        if (started)
        {
            End.X = MousePosition.X;
            End.Y = MousePosition.Y;
            /*
            here I want to get the distance between Start point and End point
            here I want to get the time interval 
            */

        }
    }

    //here ends the problematic part

   
}
public class Ball
{
    public PictureBox ball;
    public int vx, vy;
    public static UInt16 friction_coef;
    public Point Center;
    public Ball(ref PictureBox p, int x = 0, int y = 0)
    {
        this.vx = x;
        this.vy = y;
        this.ball = p;
        this.Center = new Point(p.Left + p.Width / 2, p.Top + p.Height / 2);
    }
    public static void Move(Ball b, in Form f)
    {
        if (b.ball.Top < 0 || b.ball.Top + b.ball.Height > f.ClientSize.Height)
        {
            b.vx *= -1;
        }
        if (b.ball.Left < 0 || b.ball.Left + b.ball.Width > f.ClientSize.Width)
        {
            b.vy *= -1;
        }
        b.ball.Top += b.vx;
        b.ball.Left += b.vy;    
        b.Center.X = b.ball.Left + b.ball.Width / 2;
        b.Center.Y = b.ball.Top + b.ball.Height / 2;
    }
    public static double distance(Point P1, Point P2)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt((P1.X - P2.X) * (P1.X - P2.X) + (P1.Y - P2.Y) * (P1.Y - P2.Y));
    }
}
```

The problem is that Form1_MouseDown is not triggered by a click on ball, which is obvious, but I want to make the transition from a ball click to Form1_MouseUp (which is outside the ball), without losing the state started on a ball click.

After testing this code it may be that my idea is wrong and I ran out of ideas regarding the implementation.

Comment: That's a lot of code dump.  Tell us what parts are working, and which parts are NOT working.  Narrow it down for us.

Comment: Instead of a Timer, start a [StopWatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-3.1) to determine how long the user held the mouse down.  You could also just use a DateTime and store DateTime.Now on mouse down and then again on mouse up.  Subtract the two DateTimes to get a TimeSpan.

Comment: The Timer just gets in the way.  Store the DateTime.Now, like Idle said, and then calculate the interval on mouse up.

Comment: Also, What bearing will time have on calculating force?  If I recall these games are usually done based on the length of the pull, not the time it takes to make the pull.

Comment: @SamAxe From reading this, I'm imagining (if it's a billiards-style game) that you would hold down the button and slowly power up the cue, then when you release, it would strike the cue-ball with an amount of energy proportional to how long you held down the button.  I agree that another approach might be to represent the amount of energy by an on-screen distance or pointer displacement (length of pull). Your idea has the nice analogy of how far you have to bring your arm back to make a more powerful strike.

Comment: Andrei, your question is "how to apply a click impulse" but the answer to that is "use a physics engine".  A physics engine is no small thing.  You can use a 3rd party one (we're not going to recommend one here), or you can try to craft your own.  Or is there a specific aspect of applying an impulse that you're struggling with?  What's the problem?  Math?  Timing mouse clicks?  Animation?  Please describe exactly what you are looking for.